# Joomla Off Line

Tags: joomla, offline

My site administrator login is not working.Error is "off-line" this only displaying in my administrator page.I am checking only "global check-in" option only.but next time i loggedin my administrator Login its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Go  to Joomla home folder, and edit: configuration.php - chang the line:

```
 public $offline = '1';
```

to:

```
 public $offline = '0';
```